# Backpacking - travelling with 'smart' clothes

Tags: backpacking, clothing

I've heard the tips for keeping your clothes unwrinkled in general - rolling t-shirts, having those cell things for shirts in your bag, etc.

However, while those work pretty well for t-shirts and casual clothes, every so often I've had to travel with smart trousers, business shirts, or (recently) a suit!

I didn't risk it, and carried the suit separately, having had that go badly in previous times.  However, I can't find an easy way to travel **with a backpack** and not have creases in my business shirts.  IF the destination has an iron, that's all good.  However they sometimes don't, and in deed last time for the first time, I burnt my shirt in the process (it was not a good start).

Any solid techniques for keeping clothes uncreased in a backpack?

Comment: What are `those cell things for shirts`? I'm interested...

Comment: Like this: http://www.kathmandu.com.au/Product/40326 - keeps them all together, and so when you unpack you just pick up the irrelevant cells, take them out of your bag, and open the one you need.

Comment: Oh, you meant ditty bags... Didn't understand it initially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. In my experience, rolling worked fine for trousers, but for a shirt, it is not efficient enough.
2. Ankur's suggestion of wrinkle-free clothes is a must. Keep at-least one set of wrinkle-free clothes handy.
3. I normally keep my clothes in plastic bags, they are very good to avoid wrinkles. Just keep in mind that only one cloth should be kept in one plastic bag.

Lastly I came across this link http://www.onebag.com/pack.html. Though I have not practiced it yet, the person seems to know what he is talking about. I'ld be glad to know what you all think of it.

Answer (score 7):

Attach a dedicated bag for your suit (flat packed of course) to the outside of your backpack? Seems like the only good way to do it, tbh, outside of having it couriered between places you need it.

Answer (score 6):

Surprisingly, according to other business travellers, the answer - [yet again](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3492/108) - [seems to be roll up your clothes](http://www.marketingtechblog.com/how-to-pack-a-suit-roll-it-up/):

> At Midway Airport I got into a conversation with another traveler and
>   I mentioned that my suit was packed in my carry-on bag. The guy
>   couldn’t believe that I had a suit in my bag.

Not much luck with dress shirts though:

> I don’t seem to have as much luck with dress shirts – I usually wind
>   up ironing them at the hotel.

Regardless, I would suggest buying wrinkle-free shirts and trousers for such purposes. I had to pack a change of clothes in my backpack because I had to go for a company dinner after work (didn't want to go back home to change), and having flat-packed **wrinkle-free** clothes helped as they didn't look bad once unpacked.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're using a front loading backpack, right? If so, why don't you make a plastic or cardboard box that fits your smart clothes (add some straps inside to keep everything tight) and use it as a container for "keeping the wrinkles out". :D

Don't know about you guys but I usually never pack my backpack to the top and have enough room for about two or three winter vests (just an example) so that's where you DIY suit container can fit.

Not that you asked but there are travel irons that are neither heavy nor big so consider that as well if you don't carry your suit every time you travel.

Answer (score 2):

[Onebag.com](http://www.onebag.com/) at the end of the page dedicated to [Clothes and Laundry](http://www.onebag.com/travel-clothes.html) advises to simply rent the suit when needed. But I presume that in a place without iron, such renting service will be hard to find.

Comment: and more expensive than taking a suit and having it dry-cleaned!